Can You Replace an Aberrant Mind Sorcerer Spell with a Spell and Learn the Replaced Spell as a Standard Sorcerer Spell During the Same Level-Up
Let's say I want to know Detect Thoughts. I do have that spell as a freebie from my bloodline, but say I want to retrain Detect Thoughts into Tasha's Mind Whip. I think that Detect Thoughts would be a good candidate for replacement, but I also would like to learn it as my level 3 spell since it's on the standard Sorcerer's spell list. I know this is a weird idea, but I do think there's some merit to having Mind Whip fueled by the 6th-level feature while still having the utility of Detect Thoughts and the unique position of being a Sorcerer that can cast Calm Emotions (aside from Divine Souls of course). Can I actually do this by RAW, or is this a rules violation in some way?

Yes, probably, but you should still double-check with the DM
The rules seem to support this maneuver, but some of them may not sit well with some DMs—it is always better to check with a DM ahead of time than to spring something on them.
Can you replace Detect Thoughts with Tasha’s Mind Whip?
Yes, Psionic Spells says you can replace any of the listed spells with another of the same level that is a divination or enchantment and is on the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list. Tasha’s Mind Whip is a 2nd-level enchantment on both the sorcerer and wizard spell lists, so that is definitely legal.
Can you still learn Detect Thoughts normally?
Yes, simply because nothing says you can’t. Psionic Spells provides rules for losing the spell that you gained from that feature, and they don’t say anything about blocking any other ability that might allow you to learn the replaced spell. Since Detect Thoughts is on the sorcerer spell list, you can learn it through your sorcerer spellcasting ability and Psionic Spells does nothing to change or prevent that.
Can you do it all in one level?
Yes, nothing says you have to resolve your new class features in any particular order, so you can handle Psionic Spells first—and replace Detect Thoughts with Tasha’s Mind Whip—and then you can handle your gains in your Spells feature after that, at which point you won’t know Detect Thoughts and will be allowed to learn it.
Note that while you can replace a Psionic Spell the same level you gained it, some people don’t like it (often arguing that the use of the past-tense “gained” in the clause means it has to be a spell you got at a prior sorcerer level). You may want to double-check with your DM on this point. Though even if blocked from doing this all in one level, you can always just do it at 6th, after having gained Detect Thoughts as a Psionic Spell at 5th. Since you don’t have Psionic Sorcery until 6th anyway, it won’t make a difference.
Does Psionic Sorcery apply to the replacement spells gained through Psionic Spells?
This is the biggest question mark in the whole scheme, to me:

When you cast any spell of 1st level or higher from your Psionic Spells feature,

(Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything, pg. 68)
What does it mean to be a “spell […] from your Psionic Spells feature”? Is it any spell that happens via that feature, or specifically the spells on the Psionic Spells table?
Ultimately, as written, it’s any spell you gained through that feature, including the replacement spells. If it was supposed to be only the spells on the Psionic Spells table, it should say “Psionic Spells table” instead of “Psionic Spells feature.”
But you’ll want to clear this with your DM. For my money, it looks fine—but some DMs may feel that it seems unintended. For what it’s worth, the only answer to our Q&A on the subject says it works.
